# What is WmiPrvSE.exe and why is it constantly hogging CPU?

Tags: windows, windows-10

File properties list `WmiPrvSE.exe` as WMI Host Provider.  My laptop has 4 cores and the process usually consumes 20-25% of the CPU time (so I am assuming a full core) for good chunks of time - usually when I need it the most.

What does this appliaction do and how can I get it to calm down?

My laptop is on Windows 10 v1903.

Comment: I would start by looking in the Windows WMI-ActivityTrace event log to see what process is making the WMI queries and what they are.  You have to enable the trace log first,  I would suggest enable it for maybe a minute when you have the issue.  Look at event id 11 in that event log at the clientprocessid value and map that back to the process in task manager.

Comment: @HelpingHand How does one enable the trace log?

Comment: Well via the UI, open the Windows Event Viewer (eventvwr). From the view menu choose to show Anal;ytic and Debug logs.  Then navigate down to: Applications and Services Logs - Microsoft - Windows - WMI-Activity.  Under that you should see a Trace log, you can right click on that to enable and disable.  I wouldn't leave it running for too long and disable it once you have a good sample of events during the problem.  Of course, you may want to have Task Manager/Process Explorer open to look at the process IDs that are referenced in the Events while they are still running.